# Importing mesh from blender causes distortion

Tags: three.js, blender

I'm trying to load a skinned mesh from blender into a THREE.js scene, but it... looks a little odd:

[image: Distorted mesh]

There is a skeleton that was loaded from the animation only, the mesh modified for the game, and there is a little one that is directly loaded from the three.js ObjectLoader.

It's supposed to look more like this (from blender):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

when exporting from blender, I modified the number of influences to 4. It appears that some vertices were being modified by more than one bone and therefore when only two influencing bones were exported it distorted.

[image]